# Exportar dos DataGridViews a un archivo Excel

Tags: c#, windows-forms, interop

Tengo que agregar la información de dos DataGridViews **en una misma hoja de Excel** consecutivamente. Este es el código que tengo que solo sirve para un solo DataGridView.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application 
    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet 
    ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

ws.Name = "Exported from gridview";

ws.Rows.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}

// sizing the columns
ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();


wb.SaveAs("c:\\output.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
    Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

app.Quit();
```

Comment: tienen las mismas columnas los datagrids?

Comment: Si, son las mismas columnas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El segundo empieza donde termina el primero

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count  ; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1 +dataGridView1.Rows.Count ; i++)
```

Exactamente como hiciste con el primero

ejemplo:

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}
int crow = dataGridView1.Rows.Count //empezamos donde termino
//crow es la fila donde termino el dgv1 empezamos ahi.
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[crow, i] = dataGridView2.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}
//empezamos desde crow + 1 y nos movemos dgv2.rows.count filas
for (int i = crow + 1; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count + crow - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

como veras la idea es desplazarse crow lugares y hacer lo mismo que hicimos con dgv1, ten en cuenta que no esta probado asi que puede haber algun desperfecto con los indices y demas. pero esa es la idea.

Comment: me podrías decir en que parte del codigo lo debo de colocar por favor?

Comment: Ahi puse el ejemplo, puedes espaciar las dos tablas agregando mas filas a crow

Comment: Gracias si me funcionó